# Is it possible to use TypeScript objects to dispatch redux actions (and how)?

Tags: angular, redux

I am trying to integrate Redux into my Angular app (Angular 6).
I am using https://github.com/angular-redux/store an tried following this approach for it: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/151/Angular-Ngrx-Store-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-State-Management

In this tutorial, when the action is dispatched it using the object to do it:

`this.store.dispatch(new TutorialActions.AddTutorial({name: name, url: url}) )`

It seems like it works fine with `ngrx/store` but not with `angular-redux/store`. In order to make it work, I have to stringify the object, like so:

```
@dispatch()
  dispatchFetchDomainRequest() {
    return JSON.stringify(new DomainActions.FetchDomainsRequest());
  }
```

Is there a way to use objects without `stringify`ing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  NgRX may allow dispatching class instances, but the original Redux library *only* allows dispatching plain objects as actions.  If you dispatch anything that is *not* a plain object, and that value actually reaches the store instead of being stopped by a middleware, it will explicitly throw an error.